# Authors and affiliations in the YAML of RMarkdown

Tags: yaml, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I know this question was already asked in the past in this forum ([1](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRvauGlZjeAhXMx4UKHWBeDkMQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F29532214%2Fadd-author-affiliation-in-r-markdown-beamer-presentation&usg=AOvVaw35DvCYdCbXc9f8BcMfBJcK), [2](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRvauGlZjeAhXMx4UKHWBeDkMQrAIoADAAegQICRAK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F46136924%2Fhow-to-add-multiple-authors-and-multiple-affiliations-in-rmarkdown&usg=AOvVaw2FPil8dlHRXtngIGreNHsn), [3](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRvauGlZjeAhXMx4UKHWBeDkMQrAIoAjAAegQICRAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F26043807%2Fmultiple-authors-and-subtitles-in-rmarkdown-yaml&usg=AOvVaw07zhr4PUpxbfI9WwIuJRW-)). Before you mark this as duplicated, I tried all the answers with no success. Most of the questions were asked long ago, and some updates related with `pandoc` might affect nowadays results.

The issue is that I am writing a scientific paper using RMarkdown, and would like to export the results either in HTML, PDF or Word files.

More importantly is that **there are 12 authors** signing the papers. **Some of the authors present more than one affiliation**, and **some authors presenting the same affiliation**.

My question is very clear: How can I edit the YAML to include all the authors with all the affiliations in the YAML in order to export to different formats (HTML, PDF, DOC)?

I tried this YAML:

```
---
title: "My title"
author:
  - name: Mario Modesto-Mata^1,2^
    email: paleomariomm@gmail.com
  - name: Christopher^1^
  - name: Seaghán Mhartain^2^
  - name: Rita Yuri Ynoue^1^
address:
  - code: 1
    address: Instituto de Astronomía, Geofísica e Ciências Atmosféricas, Universidade de São Paulo
  - code: 2
    address: Faculdade de Medicina, Universidade de São Paulo
date: "1 October 2018"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  word_document:
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    css: Scripts accesorios/estiloboton.css
    number_sections: yes
    theme: sandstone
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
bibliography: references.bib
csl: science.csl
---
```

## PDF output

This is what I see when I export to PDF the `.Rmd` file:

[image]

Instead of the authors, I see `true` and no affiliations.

## HTML output

I see the authors and not all the affiliation numbers. The affiliations themselves remain hidden.

[image]

## DOCX output

Neither names nor affiliations appear in the final Word file.

## My system

I am using the latest RStudio version (Version 1.1.453), running on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.

## UPDATE: original example

```
---
title: "My title"
author:
  - Mario Modesto-Mata:
      email: paleomariomm@gmail.com
      institute: [cenieh, ucl1, ppex]
      correspondence: true
  - M. Christopher Dean:
    institute: [ucl2, nhm]
  - Yuliet Quintino:
    institute: ubu
  - Rebeca García-González:
    institute: ubu
  - Rodrigo S. Lacruz:
    institute: nyu
  - Timothy G. Bromage:
    institute: nyu
  - Cecilia García-Campos:
    institute: [cenieh, ucl1]
  - Marina Martínez de Pinillos:
    institute: cenieh
  - Laura Martín-Francés:
    institute: [bor, cenieh]
  - María Martinón-Torres:
    institute: [cenieh, ucl1]
  - Eudald Carbonell:
    institute: [iphes, urv]
  - Juan Luis Arsuaga:
    institute: [isciii, ucm]
  - José María Bermúdez de Castro:
    institute: [cenieh, ucl1]
institute:
  - cenieh: Centro Nacional de Investigación sobre la Evolución Humana (CENIEH), Paseo Sierra de Atapuerca 3, 09002, Burgos, Spain
  - ucl1: Department of Anthropology, University College London, London, WC1H 0BW, UK
  - ucl2: Department of Cell and Developmental Biology, University College London, Gower Street, London, WC1E 6BT, UK
  - ubu: Laboratorio de Evolución Humana, Unierisdad de Burgos, Edificio I+D+i, Burgos, Spain
  - ppex: Equipo Primeros Pobladores de Extremadura, Casa de Cultura Rodríguez Moñino, Cáceres, Spain
  - nhm: Centre for Human Evolution Research (CHER), Department of Earth Sciences, Natural History Museum, London, SW7 5BD, UK
  - nyu: New York University
  - bor: De la Préhistoire à l'Actuel - Culture, Environnement et Anthropologie, University of Bordeaux, CNRS, MCC, PACE, UMR 5199 F_33615, Pessac Cedex, France
  - iphes: Institut Català de Paleoecologia Humana i Evolució Social (IPHES), Zona Educacional 4, Campus Sescelades, Edifici W3, Universitat Rovira i Virgili, Tarragona, Spain
  - urv: Àrea de Prehistòria, Universitat Rovira i Virgili, Avinguda de Catalunya 35, 43002, Tarragona, Spain
  - isciii: Centro mixto UCM-ISCIII de Evolución y Comportamiento humanos, Madrid, Spain
  - ucm: Departamento de Geodinámica, Estratigrafía y Paleontología, Facultad de Ciencias Geológicas, Universidad Complutense de Madrid, Spain
date: "1 October 2018"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
  html_document:
    css: Scripts accesorios/estiloboton.css
    number_sections: yes
    theme: sandstone
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
bibliography: references.bib
csl: science.csl
---
```

Comment: Hi did you find an alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is, to the best of my knowledge, no one-size-fits-it-all solution as of now.

If the target was only PDF, I'd suggest [rticles](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles) by RStudio. It's great.

A solution which also works with docx is more difficult. One possibility is to use pandoc [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org).  The [repository collecting useful filters](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters) contains two filters which will help you: [scholarly-metadata](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/scholarly-metadata) and [author-info-blocks](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/author-info-blocks). (Disclosure: I wrote these.)

Place the `.lua` files in your directory, change the YAML structure a bit, and instruct pandoc to run the filters:

```
---
title: "My title"
author:
  - Mario Modesto-Mata:
      email: paleomariomm@gmail.com
      institute: [astro, med]
      correspondence: true
  - name: Christopher
    institute: astro
  - name: Seaghán Mhartain
    institute: med
  - name: Rita Yuri Ynoue
    institute: astro
institute:
  - astro: Instituto de Astronomía, Geofísica e Ciências Atmosféricas, Universidade de São Paulo
  - med: Faculdade de Medicina, Universidade de São Paulo
date: "1 October 2018"
output: 
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua'
      - '--lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua'
---
```

This will be the PDF output:

[image: example pdf output]

while this is what it looks like in Word:

[image]

The affiliation and contact information is added to the body text, which is why the toc is displayed above it.

Comment: I dowloaded both filters `.lua` and placed in my directory folder. However, it gives an error saying *unrecognized option* and `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2`.

Comment: Seems to be an old pandoc version. Can you update RStudio?

Comment: It's my last version of RStudio. Is there a way to update pandoc alone?

Comment: According to my Linux version, I have installed the 1.19.2.4 of Pandoc

Comment: I updated pandoc to the version 2.3 downloading the `.deb` file in the official webpage. Now I get `Error running filter scholarly-metadata.lua:
Error while running filter function:
[string "scholarly-metadata.lua"]:95: not a named object: table: 0x66be820
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83 Execution halted`

Comment: That's odd. Has the YAML metadata been updated according to the schema I posted above? The script won't be able to handle your original method of specifying metadata, so that might be the cause. Can you try in a new document using just the snippet I posted?

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work with the example shown, but not with the real one. I updated the question including the original. What might be wrong with the real one? The error is the same as two comments before...

Comment: Thanks. The author's `institute` fields should be indented by two more spaces. It works for me if I do that.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to [open an issue](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/issues) on GitHub if you have other problems, wishes, or feature requests.